# Determine if the language of words with same number of 1's and 2's is context-free or not

Tags: finite-automata, context-free

$$L_2=\{w \in \{0,1,2\}^* : \text{$w$ has the same number of $1$'s and $2$'s}\}$$

I have tried creating PDA to determine if this was context-free or not. It seems like it would be because whenever a 1 is pushed onto the stack, there always is a 2 to get pop it out. The 0's are what is bothering me at the moment. Do we need to include them, or we can exclude them entirely?

I would do this with pumping lemma, but we did not learn that for our class.

Comment: The language is context-free. When a 0 is encountered, you can either not push anything in the stack, if that's allowed. If it's not allowed, you can pop its top symbol and push it back, which is the same as pushing nothing additional.

Comment: Production rule: $S \rightarrow \epsilon |0| SS|1S2|2S1$

Answer (score 1):

When it comes up to deciding if a language is context-free or not, I try the following 'roadmap' to come up with an answer.

$1.$ Try to make a CFG for the given language. If we can make a CFG, we have proved that the language is context-free.

$2.$ If step $1$ did not work out, there is a probabilty that the language is not context-free. So try proving that the given language is not context-free by the [pumping lemma](https://web.iitd.ac.in/%7Ebspanda/pumpinglemmacfl.pdf).

$3.$ If I fail to prove that language is not context-free, I probably failed to make a CFG so I start to make a PDA.

*Remark*: This is my way to (dis)prove context-free languages, there are many other ways to do this. So don't take this as a general step-by-step plan.

In your example, we need to (dis)prove $$L_2=\{w \in \{0,1,2\}^* : \text{$w$ has the same number of $1$'s and $2$'s}\}$$

So when we think of a CFG, we should consider that whenever we add a $1$, we should also add a $2$ (and vice-versa), as $|1| = |2|$. We also know that the language can be empty and that the number of $0$'s do not matter.

So

$$S \rightarrow \epsilon $$
$$S \rightarrow 0S$$
$$S \rightarrow 1S2S$$
$$S \rightarrow 2S1S$$

As we were able to make a CFG, we can say that the language $L_2$ is a CFL.

Comment: This obviously generated strings where the number of 1s an 2s is equal. You need to prove that it finds all of them. Which isn’t difficult, but not obvious.

Answer (score -1):

The above language is context free,whenever we encounter any symbol in input we can push it into stack or pop something out of stack or we simply skip that symbol according to definition of pda,so here the condition is that number of 1's and 2's must be equal so we design pda in such a way that when ever we encounter 1 we push that into stack and whenever 2is encountered we pop 1 out of stack and when we encounter 0 we simply skip it at the end stack will be empty and final state is reached if 1's and 2's are equal otherwise they halt at non final.